# Robots.txt usage

Tags: robots.txt

Google have just thrown up thousands of errors for duplicate content on my link tracker I am using.

I want to make it so Google & any other search engines do not visit my pages on the link tracker.

I want these pages to disallow these robots, my pages are:

```
http://www.site.com/page1.html
http://www.site.com/page2.html
```

How would I write my robots.txt to make all robots not visit these links when they are in my page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `robots.txt` containing the following text:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /page1.html
Disallow: /page2.html
```

The file must then be placed at `http://www.site.com/robots.txt`.

For more information, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt#Examples).

In addition, Google has a [robots.txt tester](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449&from=35237&rd=1), available from their Webmaster Tools, which lets you verify that it is formatted correctly.

Comment: I just created this, does it look ok?

Comment: User-agent: *
Disallow: /page1.html
Disallow: /page2.html
Allow: /

Comment: This version is perfect!

Comment: When using the Google webmaster tool to Fetch as Google Bot, I did it on page2.html after editing the robots.txt, and it got all of the information out of it and the request was a Success. Does this mean it's not working?

Comment: The "Allow: /" is not needed! You need to use Allow when you disallow an entire directory but you want to allow just some pages inside that dir ;)

Comment: I seemed to fix it by using User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /disclaimer.html
Disallow: /tracking.html

Upon writing this, i figured if I disallow two things, then declare allow / after it, I'm negating the disallowed links above it surely? So if I put the Allow and then the two Disallows below it, it allows all then disallows the specified pages.. makes sense right? Upon changing it to this and running the google spider check, the two pages were denied by robots.txt but all other files on my site are allowed. Is the allow thing useless?

Answer (score 0):

robots.txt must be placed in the root of your website, ad it will contain:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: page1.html
Disallow: page2.html
```

"User-agent: *" means that every SE will not follow links on the disallow dirs / pages

Edit: You should also place this meta tag inside your page1 and page2

```
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"/>
```